# Perl: saving cover from MP3 ID3-Tags in external JPG file

Tags: perl, file, mp3, jpeg, cover

Im trying to save the image data from am id3 tag to an jpg file

My actual script reads the image data and writes it to a file, whichs code looks exact like the original image file, but if i open it it looks like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3ZDd.jpg
Original picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6XCK.jpg

I use the following code:

```
use MP3::Tag;
use strict;
use warnings;

    my $filepath = "test.mp3";

    my $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($filepath);
    $mp3->get_tags();

    my $id3v2_tagdata   = $mp3->{ID3v2};
    my $info            = $id3v2_tagdata->get_frame("APIC");
    my $imgdata         = $$info{'_Data'};

     $mp3->close();

open (COVER, ">test.jpeg");
print COVER "$imgdata";
close (COVER);
```

Wheres my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might need to open the filehandle in binary mode:

Straight from the [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) documentation:  *"In other words: regardless of platform, use binmode() on binary data, like images, for example."*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

...

open my $fh, '>:raw', 'test.jpeg';
binmode $fh;
print $fh $imgdata;
close $fh;
```

Read [`PerlIO`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) for more information on opening files in different modes.  I included both `'>:raw'` and `binmode $fh` in the above code to increase familiarity, but these indicators are actaully equivalent as you'd read in PerlIO.  So feel free to use just one or the other.

Comment: You don't need both `binmode` and the open mode `>:raw`. You should also test the success of the `close`, which is much more likely to fail than the `open`.

Comment: @Borodin Aye, I said as much after my recommendation to read [`PerlIO`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html).  Figured showing both in code would be helpful just to increase familiarity, and because it doesn't actually hurt anything.  As for [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) being more likely to throw an error than [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), that isn't my experience.  However, normally I just encourage the use of [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) to cover all those cases.  Added to the above.